# Select excel sheets with user inputted string

Tags: excel, vba

I've been at this for a while and I don't understand why it's not working.  The code works in selecting sheets if I used a value like "New", but I can't get cString to work.

```
Sub SelectTabWithString()


    Dim cString As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet, flg As Boolean
    cString = Application.InputBox("Enter Characters")
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) Like cString Then
            ws.Select Not flg
            flg = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have 10 sheets, 6 in blue and 4 in green. 5 of the blue ones are named "Blue1", "Blue2", etc. I entered "blue" in the InputBox. For some reason, after I enter "blue", the program just switches back to the VBA window.

Comment: I learn something new every day - I didn't even realise that you could use a `.Select False` in order to add an extra sheet to the currently selected sheet(s).  FWIW - the code works for me.  What are you entering in the InputBox, and what sheet names currently exist?

Comment: I have 10 sheets, 6 in blue and 4 in green.  5 of the blue ones are named "Blue1", "Blue2", etc.  I entered "blue" in the InputBox.  For some reason, after I enter "blue", the program just switches back to the VBA window.

Comment: Ahh - you would need to enter "blue*" for a `Like` to work.  If you want the users to be able to just enter "blue", you should use `If Instr(LCase(ws.Name), LCase(cString)) > 0 Then`.

Comment: Ha! It works! Thank you so much!

Comment: See my edited comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have sheet names such as "Blue1", "Blue2", "Blue3", the current code will work if the user enters "blue*".

If you want the user to just be able to enter "blue", then you should change your `If` statement to:

```
If Instr(LCase(ws.Name), LCase(cString)) > 0 Then
```